# Two commands to move files to trash. What's the difference?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

`trash-cli` provide a `trash` command, and `gvfs-bin` provides a `gvfs-trash` command that move files / directories to the trash can.

Is there an important difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`gvfs-trash` is part of GNOME's Gvfs, while `trash-cli` is a separate set of tools independent of the desktop environment. Both programs implement the [XDG *Trash* specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec/) and should be compatible with each other. For example, you can trash files with `gvfs-trash` or GNOME Nautilus, then restore from `trash-restore` or KDE.

Comment: Very clear answer. In other words, the difference (in terms of their functionality) is nonexistent or minimal (in command line options).

Comment: Is the equivalent in KDE, `ktrash`?

Comment: Use gio trash filename instead, because as 2018 gvfs-trash is deprecated.